# Preserving the content in valgrind's log files when using --trace-children and execl()

Tags: c, exec, valgrind

I am currently cleaning up an existing codebase, and ran across an issue involving valgrind that I'd like to fix as it causes useful information to go lost. Valgrind is called as such:

```
/usr/bin/valgrind --leak-check=full -v --log-file=./log/valgrind/valgrind-%p.log --trace-children=yes ./myapp arg1 arg2 >&! $logfile
```

The program in question is a server which has built-in restart functionality which is implemented through `execl()`.

When the server is restarted everything collected in the logfile thus far (`./log/valgrind/valgrind-1234.log`) gets wiped out: the top of the logfile displays the arguments that are passed when a restart happens. Anything prior to it (observed to have existed using `tail -f`) exists no longer.

On one hand, it makes sense seeing how it is a fresh process image that has started execution. On the other hand, I didn't run valgrind on the previous incarnation to simply see its hard work disappear!

Does anyone know of a way to make valgrind append to its own log files as opposed to starting them out fresh? If at all possible, I want to avoid switching to valgrind's `--log-socket` because I don't want to run another server: I'm currently cleaning house and adding complexity is the exact opposite of what we need right now. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible solution to your problem could be letting valgrind logging to specified file descriptor and this way you can appended to the log file:
`valgrind --log-fd=9 9>>test.log ./app`

Comment: Hmm. That is an idea I hadn't considered. I may have to implement another form of log rotation (%p indirectly did that in case of conflicts, after all), but it sounds very credible. I'll give it a shot, and if it works out, you'll notice! :)

Comment: Success! I ended up having to rewrite the entire script (old csh script, ugh!) into bash, but the end result is that I now have a neatly organized folder with logs that don't get overwritten anymore. Thanks!